# Deleting multiple records based on specific conditions in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a button that will delete all expired records from the database, but not sure exactly as to how to achieve this. I think I got the controller part set up correctly, but im not sure what to put in the routes and the code for the button itself to delete the desired records. This is what I have in my controller:

```
      def delete_expired
        @expired_sales = Sale.where('offer_end <= ?', Date.today)
        @expired_sales.destroy_all
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Successfully Deleted Sales.'
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place an ajax button somewhere on the site with the following:

`link_to "Delete All", some_route_to_delete_expired_path, remote: true,  method: :delete`

Add to your routes.rb:

`delete 'some_controller_name/delete_expired`

And remove the `redirect_to` line as you don't need to do anything when you call this method via ajax.

Comment: Would I need to do anything in routes in this case?

Comment: `DELETE 'controller_name/delete_expired'`

Comment: Im getting this error now: undefined method `DELETE' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x3bf9358>

Comment: Oh my mistake! `delete` should be lowercase.

Comment: now im getting this error: undefined local variable or method `route_to_delete_expired_path'

Comment: Yes that's alias text I used for the route you just now created because I didn't know the name of your controller - run `rake routes` from the console to see the correct path to put in there.

Comment: Great! I will edit the answer to include the routing.